# Spring Boot data not persisting in PostgreSQL database

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a PostgreSQL table created with a query that automatically inserts a timestamp when a new entry is added to the database. I am trying to store data in the table using a Spring Boot application, but the data is not being stored based on the numb column, instead it seems to be using the ID column by default. How can I ensure that the data is stored in the table based on the numb column rather than the ID column?

This is my code:

// database query to create table

```
CREATE TABLE public.mydb 
(
    numb varchar(15) NOT NULL,
    "on_off" varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT EXTRACT(epoch FROM (now() AT TIME ZONE 'utc'::text))
);
```

// controller

```
   @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+"-----------------------------------"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"----------"+"inside controller");
        CompletableFuture<User> future = userService.createUser(user);
        String locationUrl = "/status/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString(); // generate a unique URL for the status check
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(URI.create(locationUrl));
        return new ResponseEntity<>("", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

// service

```
  @Override
    @Async("asyncExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<User> createUser(User user) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId()+"-----------------------------------"+System.currentTimeMillis()+"-------------inside services");
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(userRepository.save(user));
    }
```

// model

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="mydb")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column
    private String numb;
    @Column
    private String on_off;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    @GeneratedValue
    private String timestamp;


    public User(String numb, String on_off) {
        this.numb = numb;
        this.on_off = on_off;
    }


    public String getNumb() {
        return numb;
    }

    public void setNumb(String numb) {
        this.numb = numb;
    }

    public String getOn_Off() {
        return on_off;
    }

    public void setOn_Off(String on_off) {
        this.on_off = on_off;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
```

The expectation is to get a solution for storing data in a PostgreSQL table based on a specific column(.i.e. numb) instead of the ID column in a Spring Boot application, which is not happening currently.

//output

```
21-----------------------------------1683463770492----------inside controller
34-----------------------------------1683463770495-------------inside services
Hibernate: select user0_.numb as numb1_0_0_, user0_.on_off as on_off2_0_0_, user0_.timestamp as timestamp3_0_0_ from mydb user0_ where user0_.numb=?
```

Comment: Offtopic: "timestamp" varchar(20), what is wrong with datatype timestamp? VARCHAR is most likely the worst type you could use for this. And why using epoch? That's another thing that is going to create issues in the (near) future.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but my main concern is saving the data into the database based on the number column. Can you please provide any insights on how to achieve this in a Spring Boot application?

Comment: What is your concern? You marked it as an `@Id` so I don't see the problem you have here. Onet hing I do so is that there is no transaction and probably nothing will be persisted, no tx, no persistence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database's table must have a primary key.

Comment: if you have some link of the async project of springboot because i'm working in springboot,please share with me if possible ?

Comment: @DeepakMathur I do not understand the question. Do you mean "link of the async project" or do you mean "link of a async project"?